# how to limit calculation till two decimal in sql with NVL

Tags: sql, oracle, limit

I have a quick question how can i limit the below code upto two decimal.

```
select (nvl(SUM(WEIGHT_BASE),0)* 0.453592) 
from order_release_line 
where ORDER_RELEASE_GID IN ('ULE.4222011707') 
  and IS_HAZARDOUS='Y' 
  and HAZ_IS_LIMITED_QUANTITY='Y'
```

If the number is `9524.512136358176677438677870668470859504`, the output I want is `9524.51`.

Comment: "two decimal", what you expect, [round](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions135.htm) after dot? maybe [trunc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions200.htm). Any example expected output?

Comment: Yes suppose 9524.512136358176677438677870668470859504 is the number then I want 9524.51 only

Answer (score 1):

they are two possible solutions, Trunc - simple cut number if there is more then n digits after dot, but round can give you statistically and/or financially better result...

```
SELECT Trunc(NVL(Sum(weight_base),0)* 0.453592, 2) cutted
, Round(NVL(Sum(weight_base),0)* 0.453592, 2) rounded
FROM order_release_line 
WHERE order_release_gid IN ('ULE.4222011707') 
  AND is_hazardous='Y' 
  AND haz_is_limited_quantity='Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`TRUNC` function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions200.htm).

```
select trunc((nvl(SUM(WEIGHT_BASE),0)* 0.453592),2)
from order_release_line 
where ORDER_RELEASE_GID IN ('ULE.4222011707') 
  and IS_HAZARDOUS='Y' 
  and HAZ_IS_LIMITED_QUANTITY='Y'
```

Comment: Yes suppose 9524.512136358176677438677870668470859504 is the number then I want 9524.51 only

Comment: Thank you for fixing that, @Allan. I apologize for the goofed parenthesis.